# Call INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE using DataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, database-connection, dataadapter

I have an application which is written in asp.net and C#. I am using a class with Connected mode for Insert/Update and delete statements. I have proper try, catch and Finally statements which is opening and closing the OracleConnection. But still sometimes its just getting out without closing the connection and is making locks in the DataBase, which in turn makes the website stop.

Now i thought to change the Queries into a Disconnected mode where the DataAdapter will manage the connection issues. I need to execute custom Queries with parameters.

I wrote an application where i tried calling INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements using DataAdapter objects FILL method. Its working fine.(For da.Update() method it needs a row and row state etc which i thought will be tough)

I want to know will there be any issues in performance of database or in the application if i use this method??

```
int i = 0;
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYSTRING"].ConnectionString))
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO MYTABLE(ID) VALUES(:ID)", con);           
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":ID", 123);

        using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))            
        { 
            i = da.Fill(new DataSet());
        }
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    return i;
```

The above code runs any query(insert,update,delete) which is sent to the DataAdapter. Should i do it in any other way or will this be ok??

Comment: I think I see what you are up to, and I've done something similar.  I wanted to create a sort of generic wrapper around my database layer so that I could easily call a stored procedure with a list of parameters without having to specify Insert/Update/Delete.  Using the DataAdapter.Fill() does seem to work, and I haven't noticed any performance hits either, but I'm also not sure if this is a good practice or not.  I guess I'll keep using it until I find out otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about OracleCommand Objects, but in SqlDataAdapter you have Insert Command, DeleteCommand, UpdateCommand. [DataAdapterProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter_properties.aspx) or else you can use IdbDataAdapter Interface [IDbDataAdapter Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbdataadapter.aspx)

```
yourDataAdapter.InsertCommand = YourInsertCommandObject;//
```

for Update

```
yourDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = YourUpdatcommand;
```

Comment: In the above one i don't want to specify any of these and it works perfectly. I just want to know whether any performance issues will happen in the later stages of implementation